# unable to connect to internet with osboxes.org ubuntu server 19.10 image on virtualbox

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, network-manager

I booted (in virtualbox) an ubuntu 19.10 server image obtained from [here](https://www.osboxes.org/ubuntu-server/)

To enable networking I tried to add a netplan configuration. (Adapted from [here](https://vitux.com/how-to-configure-networking-with-netplan-on-ubuntu/))

In short I created the following file: `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` with following content:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
    ethernets:
       enp0s3:
          dhcp4: yes
```

However, on the next step where I have to test the configuration I get the following error, saying NetworkManager.service not found.

[image]

Comment: We don't support custom Ubuntu builds. You can ask the people who made the builds.

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

1. Identify appropriate interface name: `ip a` will list everything
2. Open the yaml file in `/etc/netplan`. Note: open default file there. No need to create a new file as mentioned in the article linked into the question post.
3. In the file, write the configuration details (as mentioned in that same article mentioned above)

For e.g. my interface name turned out to be `enp0s3` hence content in the config file was:

```
network:
   version: 2
   ethernets:
       enp0s3:
           dhcp4: yes
```

4. Apply the configuration: `sudo netplan apply`

You may even test it before you apply the changes...`sudo netplan try`